# Why does riesz representation for Hilbert spaces give antilinear isomorphism

Tags: hilbert-spaces

In many sources including Wikipedia, we see that there is an antilinear isomorphism between $H$ and its dual given by $\phi(y) = \langle \cdot, y \rangle$. Why not change the definition to put $y$ in the first slot instead, and thereby get a plain old linear isomorphism?

Comment: Because then $\phi'(y)$ wouldn't be a linear functional, but an antilinear functional. (So you have a linear isomorphism between $H$ and its *anti*dual.)

Comment: Ah, I see. So there's no avoiding it.

Comment: Not if you look at complex Hilbert spaces. Since the inner product is sesquilinear and not bilinear, the conjugation must appear somewhere if you work coordinate-free. If you fix a Hilbert basis, you can give a linear (unitary) isomorphism between $H$ and its dual, but it's not canonical, that depends on the choice of basis.